What is the best approach to look at association between change in X and change in Y?
What is the correct approach to analyze the association between changes in two variables with two synchronous repeated measurements?
I have calculated delta change scores for variables
X and Y both measured twice, once at baseline and then again 1 year later (e.g., ΔX = X_year1 - X_baseline and ΔY = Y_year1 - Y_baseline)and then looked at the correlation between these change scores. However, my results show associations that are opposite to my hypotheses. I suspect that regression to the mean might be influencing my results, but I haven't found much information on how this effect impacts the association between changes in two variables.
Would a better approach be to calculate "change" using residuals from a linear model, such as X_year1 ~ X_baseline. This method would also allow me to adjust for covariates by adding them to the linear model.
Specific Questions:

How does regression to the mean affect the correlation between change scores?
Is using residuals from a linear model (e.g., X_time2 ~ X_time1) a more appropriate method to analyze changes in variables?
What are other recommended approaches to accurately assess the association between changes in two variables while controlling for baseline values and potential covariates?
Does the correct approach change if you have three vs two timepoints?

Any thoughts or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated!

Hi, how many time points do you have?

And please better define the measurements, as I don’t see subscripts for Y that correspond to subscripts for X.  Also provide details about variables you may be differencing, i.e., what is their distribution, are the interval-scaled measurements, are their any floor or ceiling effects.  Those characteristics will tell us whether subtracting values is a legal mathematical operation.
